# Problem with special character in controller in Laravel

Tags: html, laravel, utf-8

I am trying to save multiple checkbox values, and its value attributes contain special characters, such as "ç," "ã," and so on. But when I get into my controller and return the `$request` object, I see that the special characters are not being formatted in utf-8. How can I solve this, please?

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" name="servicos[]" type="checkbox"
           value="Substituição de piso nos banheiros" id="servicos1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
        Substituição de piso nos banheiros
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" name="servicos[]" type="checkbox"
           value="Instalação de piso na sala e dormitórios" id="servicos2">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
        Instalação de piso na sala e dormitórios
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" name="servicos[]" type="checkbox"
           value="Substituição de piso na cozinha" id="servicos3">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
        Substituição de piso na cozinha
    </label>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
return $request->servicos;
```

Comment: What are you getting back?

Comment: Something like this:
{"id":1,"nome":"Substitui\u00e7\u00e3o de piso nos banheiros","created_at":"2022-04-28T03:55:54.000000Z","updated_at":null}

Comment: Even when I save it in a separated table and try to retrieve it...

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to share a [mcve].